# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerToken' of undefined

Tags: solidity, web3js

i want to return owner of contract address :

i write this contract :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

import "./Token.sol";

contract KIA is Token {
    Token private token;

    constructor(
        address owner,
        uint256 initSupply,
        string memory tokenName,
        string memory tokenSymbol,
        uint8 decimalUnits
    ) Token(owner, initSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol, decimalUnits) {}

    function ownerToken() external view returns (address) {
        return token.owner();
    }

    function BuyToken(uint256 rate) external payable {
        uint256 tokenAmount = msg.value * rate;
        token.transfer(msg.sender, tokenAmount);
    }
}
```

and this contract inheritance from Token :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

import "./SafeMath.sol";

contract Token is SafeMath {
    uint256 public totalToken;
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint256 public decimals;
    address tokenOwner;

    mapping(address => uint256) public balance;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowed;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    constructor(
        address owner,
        uint256 initSupply,
        string memory tokenName,
        string memory tokenSymbol,
        uint8 decimalUnits
    ) {
        balance[owner] = initSupply;
        totalToken = initSupply;
        name = tokenName;
        symbol = tokenSymbol;
        decimals = decimalUnits;
        tokenOwner = owner;
    }

    //
    modifier transferFromModifire(
        address _to,
        address _from,
        uint256 _value
    ) {
        require(_value <= 0, " value can not be 0  ");
        require(balance[_from] < _value, " not have enough money ");
        require(balance[_to] + _value < balance[_to], " overflow Error ");
        require(
            _value > allowed[_from][msg.sender],
            " i dont know whats error "
        );
        _;
    }

    modifier transferModifire(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        require(_value <= 0);
        require(balance[_to] + _value < balance[_to]);
        _;
    }

    // Send Owner Address
    function owner() external view returns(address) {
        return tokenOwner;
    }

    // Send Token From Owner To Address
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)
        external
        transferModifire(_to, _value)
        returns (bool)
    {
        balance[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeSub(balance[msg.sender], _value);
        balance[_to] = SafeMath.safeAdd(balance[_to], _value);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    // Send Token From Address To Address
    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    ) external transferFromModifire(_to, _from, _value) returns (bool) {
        balance[_from] = SafeMath.safeSub(balance[msg.sender], _value);
        balance[_to] = SafeMath.safeAdd(balance[_to], _value);
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

i want to test and deploy contract :

```
import assert from 'assert';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import { AbiItem } from 'web3-utils';
import * as KiaToken from '../build/KIA.json';


const web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/afa51bf9aa97452d90cbc4713d14888d');


describe("Kiaswap Contract", () => {

    let rapstoneAddress = '0xB643992c9fBcb1Cb06b6C9eb278b2ac35e6a2711';
    let initSupply = 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
    let TokenName = 'KIA';
    let tokenSymbol = 'LION';
    let decimalUnits = 8;
    let token: any;

    beforeEach(async () => {

        token = await new web3.eth.Contract(KiaToken.abi as AbiItem[])
            .deploy({
                data: KiaToken.evm.bytecode.object,
                arguments: [rapstoneAddress, initSupply, TokenName, tokenSymbol, decimalUnits]
            });
    })


    it('Owner ', async () => {
      let owner =   await token.methods.ownerToken().call();
      assert.equal(rapstoneAddress,owner);
    })


})
```

but after run this code :

```
 it('Owner ', async () => {
      let owner =   await token.methods.ownerToken().call();
      assert.equal(rapstoneAddress,owner);
    })
```

it show me error :

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerToken' of undefined
> ```

**now whats the problem ????**

Comment: The Kia contract inherits from Token and it also has a token. That is confusing, are you sure you want it that way? I'd guess you don't want `Token token;`, just remove that line and replace `token.funcXX()` with `funcXX()`.

Comment: @Ismael , thnaks but without the `Token token` i can not access to `transfer` in Token

Comment: `KIA` inherits from Token, so it can call `transfer()`. Perhaps the issue is that it is declared as `external`, try declaring it as `public` so it could be called from the inherited contract `KIA`. Also apply to function `owner`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function in Token contract with "token.function()" you have to first assign token to an inheritance of Token contract. Maybe you can change your constructor like this:

```
constructor(
    address owner,
    uint256 initSupply,
    string memory tokenName,
    string memory tokenSymbol,
    uint8 decimalUnits
) {
token = new Token(owner, initSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol, decimalUnits); }
```

Comment: no , still show me that error